# Не приходят respons-ы gRPC-клиенту на C#

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, grpc

Возникли трудности при создании gRPC-клиента на C#. Я работаю с TINKOFF INVEST API, который работает по интерфейсу gRPC.
Код клиента представлен ниже.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var metadata = new Metadata
                {
                    { "Authorization", "Bearer {token}"}
                };
            using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://invest-public-api.tinkoff.ru:443");
            var client = new MarketDataStreamService.MarketDataStreamServiceClient(channel);
            using var stream = client.MarketDataStream(metadata);
            await stream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(
                new MarketDataRequest
                {
                    SubscribeCandlesRequest = new SubscribeCandlesRequest()
                    {
                        SubscriptionAction = SubscriptionAction.Subscribe,
                        Instruments =
                        {
                                new CandleInstrument()
                                {
                                    Figi = "FUTNL0422000",
                                    Interval = SubscriptionInterval.OneMinute
                                    //Depth = 20
                                }
                        }
                    }
                });
            while (await stream.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
            {
                //В этом цикле приходит единственный респонс, дальше бесконечное ожидание
                Console.WriteLine(stream.ResponseStream.Current);
            }
        }
```

Я отправляю серверу реквест с запросом подписки на свечи. Прилетает единственный респонс:

```
{ "subscribeCandlesResponse": { "trackingId": "6225e3c561306a882d46678aa1a67bc8", "candlesSubscriptions": [ { "figi": "FUTNL0422000", "interval": "SUBSCRIPTION_INTERVAL_ONE_MINUTE", "subscriptionStatus": "SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS_SUCCESS" } ] } }
```

об успешной подписке, далее никаких сообщений не приходит.
Подскажите, что не так :(

Comment: Видимо, не прилетает респонсов из-за того, что биржа приостановила торги. Отпишу, как проверю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, запрос правильный. Респонсы не приходили, т.к. биржа была приостановлена.